# What is better to use to create the graphical interface with GTK?

Tags: xml, gtk, glade

I'm new to GTK and would like some tips to get started.
I saw that it is possible to create the graphic part both using XML (with the GtkBuilder) and using code. I like the idea of XML but is it convenient to make this choice? Are XML objects the same as code-implementable ones?

Are there guides with all (or most used) GTK XML objects?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Most GTK app developers will recommend using XML. This is the style most GNOME apps use, for instance.

There are benefits to GtkBuilder XML. It's usually easier to understand than code and provides a nice separation between UI and logic.

The XML objects are the same as the ones you build in code, and you can even mix them if you need to by creating widgets in code and adding them to containers from the UI file.

You might or might not want to use Glade; some people find writing XML manually to be easier.

As for tutorials, most language bindings have their own GtkBuilder tutorials because each language handles them differently. Try looking at the "getting started" tutorial for your language.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This sounds good for me.
Isn't GtkBuilder always the same for all GTL languages?

Comment: The XML is, but the way you integrate it into your code differs.